# Correcting MOSFET gate voltage

Tags: voltage, mosfet, resistors

I'm working on a project where a IRL520N controls some LEDs but I ran into a problem. In order to activate the MOSFET I'm using a microcontroller with an output of 5 V, but the datasheet says that the gate threshold voltage must be between 2-4 volts.

So I wondered: would putting a 200 ohm resistance at the gate fix the problem?

Comment: A little more than that. put 2k in series from the driver, 3k in shunt to the device input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gate threshold voltage is specified between 2-4 volts (actually the [datasheet I found](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRL520N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565f9b62255b) for the closest match was 1-2 V). This means that the manufacturer guarantees that if you take any genuine MOSFET of that model and measure it, the threshold will be guaranteed somewhere in that range, so a 5 V signal is guaranteed to turn the transistor on.

Being above the threshold is fine and having some margin here is actually good. Because the transistor VgsMax (maximum Vgs that the transistor can safely experience) is well above 5V, you have no concern of damaging the transistor by gate overvoltage.

The resistance at the gate is a good idea for other reasons such as [reducing ringing](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/68748/9612) when using sharp gate drive edges or inductances in the gate wire. A pulldown resistor is also helpful there.

Answer (score 6):

[IRL520N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRL520N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf) has a Vgs(th) of 1.0 to 2.0V according to the datasheet linked.

More importantly, its Rds(on) is specified at 4.0V and 5.0V drive and it will be less than 26m\$\Omega\$, which is pretty good for this application (assuming your LED supply voltage is well under the 100V rating of the MOSFET).

You can add a 200 ohm series resistor to the gate and perhaps a 20K resistor to ground in order limit peak current from the MCU when it switches on/off and in order to ensure the MOSFET turns off if the pin becomes tri-state or disconnected.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVlB8v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: actually slightly better to put the 20k from the MCU end to GND because it allows the full MCU pin V to be applied to the gate (rather than 99 %).

Comment: @jp314 yes, exactly,  but more likely it will be useless because the connection could get broken on the wrong side.